# While using Material-UI config in react-awesome-query-builder- selected field are not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-UI for the initial config for query filters. If I use more than one "struct" for grouping in fields, then during selection it is not showing the selected fields.
Config looks like this -

```
       const fields: Fields = {
        user: {
        label: "User",
        tooltip: "Group of fields",
        type: "!struct",
        subfields: {
        ...
         }
        },
      test1: {
      label: "test",
       type: "!struct",
        subfields: {
        ...
        }
      }
    }
```

This is the link of [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-demo-0w1fs), I created a demo here

Comment: this code is very difficult to follow

Comment: Yes I agree but @Vulwsztyn this is the demo code of this library that they provide. I just add a fiew fields.